# PostGIS is not seeing any GDAL drivers

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql

I've tried setting `POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS=ENABLE_ALL` as an environment variable. As well as running

```sql
SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL'; from psql. 
-- (With a pg_ctl restart after each)
```

I'm still getting 0 rows when I query

```sql
select short_name, long_name from st_gdaldrivers();
```

```
Postgres: PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn), 64-bit

PostGIS: POSTGIS="2.1.7 r13414" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.9.2" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER

GDAL: (from gdalinfo --version) GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24
```

Is there something I didn't install?

Answer (score 3):

So I had this very problem today - solved by:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/environment
```

add:

```
POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS=ENABLE_ALL
POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS=1
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  - <kbd>Y</kbd> - <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
sudo service postresql restart
```