# Understanding the differences in PostGIS full version string from two Docker images

Tags: postgis, postgresql, docker

I have to migrate a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database from [mdillon/postgis:11](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mdillon/postgis/11/images/sha256-b2a8fefe8a635025ef746db322a030f7f463d63fc7e5c37769793edcd66525a8?context=explore) to [postgis/postgis:13-3.1](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/postgis/postgis/13-3.1/images/sha256-357d3e5396486e9c0253dd59adff854ea51fe7686c4b4c5097bcb013a941c138?context=explore).

From [mdillon/postgis:11](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mdillon/postgis/11/images/sha256-b2a8fefe8a635025ef746db322a030f7f463d63fc7e5c37769793edcd66525a8?context=explore) docker image I can read:

```
# select postgis_full_version();

                        postgis_full_version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="2.5.2 r17328" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110"
 GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246"
 PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016"
 GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24"
 LIBXML="2.9.4"
 LIBJSON="0.12.1" 
 LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1"
 TOPOLOGY
 RASTER
 (1 row)
```

But from [postgis/postgis:13-3.1](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/postgis/postgis/13-3.1/images/sha256-357d3e5396486e9c0253dd59adff854ea51fe7686c4b4c5097bcb013a941c138?context=explore) docker image I can read:

```
# select postgis_full_version();

                        postgis_full_version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="3.1.0 5e2af69" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130"
 GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771"
 PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018"
 LIBXML="2.9.4"
 LIBJSON="0.12.1"
 LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.1"
 WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
 TOPOLOGY
 (1 row)
```

So, why the differences?
Especially, why the drop of `GDAL`, and `RASTER` in the, yet official, PostGIS image?
Does it mean it doesn't have gdal and raster support?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. You can however enable if required I guess, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142056/postgis-is-not-seeing-any-gdal-drivers - also the RASTER extension will have to be enabled since PostGIS 3, see https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/waiting-for-postgis-3-separate-raster-extension

Comment: Great post, thanks! I succeeded installing the RASTER extension globally. But I didn't succeeded to enable GDAL drivers following https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_gdal_enabled_drivers.html (maybe I have to install GDAL itself on the image for that to actually work and then restart the container...)

Comment: Yes, most likely. Looking forward to hearing your findings :)